# How to get a list of drivers deployed with Windows operating systems

Tags: windows, drivers

I need to create a tool that identifies drivers installed apart from the original installation and updates of a Windows operating system.

There are various tools that can be used to interrogate an installed operating system and even an offline Windows image. However, I was wondering if this information is available in other ways that would mean not having to install each of the operating systems of interest, then check again following releases of hotfixes etc. Some online catalog perhaps.

At first glance, Microsoft Update Catalog looks like the kind of thing I'm thinking of, but it does not to appear to support searching for all drivers of a given operating system. https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Faq.aspx

Comment: Given that Windows updates itself and its drivers automatically during installation based on what is installed in the system it is going to be difficult to get a definitive list that isn't in constant flux. Drivers can be updated and uploaded to Microsoft update systems at any time.

Comment: There are numerous third-party tools that will generate a list of drivers that are currently installed, but if you are trying to streamline your installation process, your best bet to simplify the process is to add those drivers to your installation image.

Comment: In short, there are no shortcuts to the information.

Comment: @Mokubai Indeed, this is the problem. The tool I need to create is to help with migration of applications from legacy operating systems and I need to suggest third-party drivers on which the application might be dependent.

Comment: @fractor - You should be installing those drivers, installing those applications, and creating the image based of a working installation.  Hopefully you are not trying to support drivers released via Windows Update.

Comment: @harrymc I was thinking that was probably the case. So it's good to extinguish the hope of other options before heading down an install-inspect-repeat cycle.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you but I am not looking to create a Windows installation image.

Comment: If software requires specific drivers, such as USB drivers for the hardware they work with, then those drivers should be supplied and installed as a part of that software installation. Outside of tinkertown generic cheapo devices the machine should also download drivers as needed and solve problems that way. Either you should already know what specific drivers are required for your application or you should be finding **that** out. Finding a list of every driver on the planet, or even just on a particular machine, and installing them all is the wrong way to go

Comment: There is no desire to install drivers other than those needed by the application. Indeed the point is to try to help discover that.

Comment: Then there is potentially an XY problem here and you are attacking it from the wrong direction. If you ask what drivers are required for a particular program to work with a specific device we might actually be able to help. That would be a new question though.

Comment: I've reworded the original question slightly as I think that may have been causing a bit of confusion "following" => "apart from".

Comment: Even with the "following" => "apart from" distinction it is impossible to nail down the problem. As I mentioned Windows updates itself during media creation (if downloaded via the website) and potentially during installation as well as immediately after. It is impossible to define what you'll get at any given point to use as a baseline to compare against with your software installed. Better to work from the side of your actual software as I mentioned already.

Comment: @Mokubai In response to your suggestion I have posted this question https://superuser.com/questions/1381595/how-to-statically-identify-sys-files-on-which-an-application-depends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative answer : There are no databases listing which drivers will be installed
for which configuration.

The number of possible combinations of hardware devices and drivers,
both Windows-generic and third-party, is simply too large and is besides
in constant evolution.

Windows installs according to the hardware it knows about at the moment,
but this decision may change in the future.
And it's not immune from making the wrong decision
(as is found in various posts on this site).

Windows never guarantees hardware support, just does the best job it can.
In many cases human intervention is required to correct the situation.

The field of hardware versus drivers is just too disorderly for any database.